# Manage user's session on a web server for an iPhone app user

Tags: php, iphone, session

I'm writing an iPhone app. This app requires users to login on a remote web server which is using php + mysql. How can the server handle this? Using sessions? Cookies? unique IDs? 
Any link/code/tutorial on how to do this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Get the webservice ready that is build up using php
> 2. On login webservice call on account of successful
>      authentication a return a random string keep it in a session
>      variable in server side and save it in a plist or sqlite db
> 3. After that every time you make a request call send a additional
>      retrieved parameter check if both are equal then process the request
>      in server side
> 4. Check if the Http response code is not 200 if so then pop all the
>      viewcontrollers and get the app to login page(It means the seesion
>      has expired or any other error.You can handle it appropriately if you read about various http response codes)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to pass session identifiers or credentials in each request, it makes sense to use `NSURLRequest`'s inbuilt cookie support to either store the entire session, or to just store a session identifier which you then use on the server to lookup the actual session data.